NGINX proxy pass not working with Laravel application. No routes other than / can be accessed from proxy domain. Gets a 404. How to solve?
I have a Laravel 7 application running on a separate server, let's assume it is SERVER A with domain serverA.com. The application is behind NGINX.
I have another server, SERVER B. I want to proxy pass serverA.com with serverB.com. I tried with bellow NGINX configs but only the / route works. No other routes work and gives a 404. For example, serverA.com/login works as expected but if I do serverB.com/login, a 404 is shown. Please help.
# Server A NGINX Config
server {

    root /var/www/html/microsite/public;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name serverA.com;

    location / {
        try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }

      location /phpmyadmin {
               root /usr/share/;
               index index.php index.html index.htm;
               location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                       try_files $uri =404;
                       root /usr/share/;
                       #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
               fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
                       fastcgi_index index.php;
                       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                       include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
               }
               location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                       root /usr/share/;
               }
        }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/serverA.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/serverA.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


server {
    if ($host = www.serverA.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = serverA.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name serverA.com www.serverA.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = serverA.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name serverA.com www.serverA.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}

# Server B NGINX Config
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name serverB.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://serverA.com;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Uri $request_uri;
    }
}


welcome, please revise your question, it is impossible to follow up what's wrong, neither you provide what you tried nore which research had been done to solve it. please read carefully [ask] Please provide also logs
